# How to trigger an action for html element that has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to use a click event handler but I have a lot of html  tags with the same "upvote" or "downvote" id. When one of them has been clicked it should trigger a function that will send some data to my view and add a user to the database. How can I separate this events.
Here is my html code:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% load static %}
{% load static_thumbnails %}
{% load thumbnail %}
{% block title %}
    News
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% for article in news %}
        <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
        <img src="{{ article.url }}">
        <p>
            <a href="{{ article.resource }}">Read from the resource</a>
            {% with article.upvotes.count as total_upvotes and article.downvotes.count as total_downvotes%}
                <span id = 'upvotes'>{{ total_upvotes }}</span>
                <a href = '#' id = 'upvote' data-id="{{ article.id }}"><img src = '{% static "images/news/upvote.png"%}'></a>
                <span id = 'downvotes'>{{ total_downvotes }}</span>
                <a href="#" id="downvote" data-id="{{ article.id }}"><img src = '{% static "images/news/downvote.png" %}'></a>
            {% endwith %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
{% block domready %}
    $('#upvote').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var action = 'upvote';
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"{% url 'news:upvote'%}",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id:id,
                action:action
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#upvotes').text(data.upvotes)
                $('#downvotes').text(data.downvotes)
            }
        })
    })
    $('#downvote').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var action = 'downvote';
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"{% url 'news:upvote'%}",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id:id,
                action:action
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#upvotes').text(data.upvotes)
                $('#downvotes').text(data.downvotes)
            }
        })
    })
{% endblock %}
```

Now I can use only first button, I don`t know why.
Other  tags just send me to the top of the page.

Comment: ID attributes MUST be unique. If they are not unique your code will not function correctly. You are better to use `event` and then target the particular nodes of interest using `event.target` and then parent/child/sibling selectors

Comment: `while having elements with the same id?` You can't have elements with the same ID. ID stands for _unique_ identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the  `class` attribute instead of the `id` attribute. Then you can get all elements having that class and loop through them in your [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/eventlistener), and check which one was clicked by comparing the current element of the loop to the event's `target`:

Here's a detailed example:

```js
// Identifies some DOM elements
const
   list = document.getElementById("list"),
   classyItems = document.getElementsByClassName("my-class");

// Calls `hightlightItem` when user clicks inside the list element
list.addEventListener("click", highlightItem);

// Defines the listener function
function highlightItem(event){ // Listener can access the triggering event

  const clickedThing = event.target; // Event's `target` property is useful

  // Makes sure the click was on an appropriate element before proceeding
  if(clickedThing.classList.contains("my-class")){

    // Loops through the collection
    for(let item of classyItems){

      // Updates the classList for the current item in the loop
      item.classList.remove("highlight");

      // Maybe updates it again before continuing to next item in loop
      if(item == clickedThing){ item.classList.add("highlight"); }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight{ background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="my-class">Elf</li>
  <li class="my-class">Dwarf</li>
  <li class="my-class">Human</li>
</ul>
```

**Nerdy details: `getElementsByClassName` and similar methods get a "live" collection, meaning if more items with that class get added to the page, the collection will update itself. In contrast, the (still very cool) `querySelectorAll` method returns a static collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the HTML you generate in your template ( presume that is templated html ) change the `id` attributes of the `span` elements to classNames and modify the hyperlinks so that `id = 'upvote'` becomes `data-action='upvote'` etc then, using `fetch` as an example to send the ajax request rather than jQuery, you could try like this:

```
{% for article in news %}
    <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
    <img src="{{ article.url }}">
    <p>
        <a href="{{ article.resource }}">Read from the resource</a>
        {% with article.upvotes.count as total_upvotes and article.downvotes.count as total_downvotes%}
            
            <span class='upvotes'>{{ total_upvotes }}</span>
            <a href='#' data-action='upvote' data-id="{{ article.id }}">
                <img src = '{% static "images/news/upvote.png"%}'>
            </a>
            
            <span class='downvotes'>{{ total_downvotes }}</span>
            <a href="#" data-action="downvote" data-id="{{ article.id }}">
                <img src = '{% static "images/news/downvote.png" %}'>
            </a>
            
        {% endwith %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

And the Javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[data-task]').forEach(a=>{
    a.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        let spup=this.parentNode.querySelector('span.upvotes');
        let spdown=this.parentNode.querySelector('span.downvotes');
        
        let fd=new FormData();
            fd.append('id',this.dataset.id);
            fd.append('action',this.dataset.action);
            
        fetch( "{% url 'news:upvote'%}", { method:'post', body:fd })
            .then( r=>r.json() )
            .then( json => {
                spup.textContent=json.upvotes;
                spdown.textContent=json.downvotes;
            })
    })
})
```